# How do I install php 5.2.10 on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, php, apt, php5, ubuntu-10.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP 5.2x on Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx](https://serverfault.com/questions/138209/php-5-2x-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx)

I'm setting up a new Ubuntu server, but it's going to be running a somewhat old PHP application that seems to have conflicts with PHP 5.3.

How do I configure Apt to give me the option to install a previous 5.2.x version of PHP?

Comment: Answered here: http://serverfault.com/questions/138209/php-5-2x-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx

Answer (score 0):

Instruction here 
http://mrkandy.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/install-php-5-2-x-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid/

Comment: This is a really hard solution to maintain. 

This page is easier to implement.
https://edge.launchpad.net/~txwikinger/+archive/php5.2